# Wordpress related error

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress website is showing me following error. I had not  changed or upladed any thing to the server. Is this error due to some WP update that might have happened automatically or due to web server configuration

> Warning: require(/home/domainName/public_html/wp-includes/post.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/DomainName/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 145
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/DomainName/public_html/wp-includes/post.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/DomainName/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 145

I am not much familiar with word-press any help in rectifying this issue would be of great help

Comment: download latest WordPress root `wp-settings.php` file, replace with root `wp-settings.php` file. Done

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if the file /home/domainName/public_html/wp-includes/post.php exits and is readable (if unix mode) ?